Discord.py bot Create Role Issue
When I create new roles, they are created above the bot role. Which makes it impossible to change their position. Because due to the role hierarchy, the bot does not have permission to do this. I have no idea why this is happening, anyone have any ideas? I don't know if the code will help here because I'm downloading the role data from the yaml file, but I'll leave the part responsible for it and the yaml file.
Code:
async def generate_role(guild):
    with open("cogs/ServerGenerator/patterns/default.yml", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as rFile:
        data = yaml.safe_load(rFile)

    for role_name, role_data in data['roles'].items():
        if role_name == "everyone":
            await guild.default_role.edit(permissions=discord.Permissions(**role_data.get('permissions', {})))
        else:
            new_role = await guild.create_role(
                name=role_data.get('name', None),
                color=int(role_data.get('color', None), 16),
                hoist=role_data.get('hoist', None),
                mentionable=role_data.get('mentionable', None),
                permissions=discord.Permissions(**role_data.get('permissions', {}))
            )

Yaml File:
roles:
  #Server Roles
  owner:
    name: "⋞ᴏᴡɴᴇʀ⋡"
    color: "e5e357"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: false
  administrator:
    name: "⋞ᴀᴅᴍɪɴ⋡"
    color: "ed0041"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  moderator:
    name: "⋞ᴍᴏᴅ⋡"
    color: "73c65a"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  booster:
    name: "⋞ʙᴏᴏsᴛᴇʀ⋡"
    color: "fb0399"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  member:
    name: "⋞ᴍᴇᴍʙᴇʀ⋡"
    color: "03d998"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  newbie:
    name: "⋞ɴᴇᴡʙɪᴇ⋡"
    color: "ccc7a"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  #Gender
  male:
    name: "ᴍᴀʟᴇ"
    color: "007fff"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  female:
    name: "ғᴇᴍ"
    color: "c601e2"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  other:
    name: "ᴏᴛʜᴇʀ〳ɴᴏɴ ʙɪ〳ᴘʀᴇғᴇʀ ɴᴏᴛ ᴛᴏ sᴀʏ"
    color: "03d998"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  #Pronouns
  he:
    name: "ʜᴇ〳ʜɪᴍ"
    color: "007fff"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  she:
    name: "sʜᴇ〳ʜᴇʀ"
    color: "c601e2"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  they:
    name: "ᴛʜᴇʏ〳ᴛʜᴇᴍ﹝+ᴏᴛʜᴇʀs﹞"
    color: "03d998"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  #Age
  18:
    name: "⊰ᴀɢᴇ⊱﹝+﹞"
    color: "9659b6"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  15:
    name: "⊰ᴀɢᴇ⊱﹝+﹞"
    color: "a060d0"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  13:
    name: "⊰ᴀɢᴇ⊱﹝+﹞"
    color: "a77dc2"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true

I tried to move the roles after it was created, but the hierarchy permissions do not allow it. I have no idea how to set the position of a role when creating it. I couldn't find anything on the internet, so I'm writing here.
bot_role = guild.me.top_role
await new_role.edit(position=bot_role.position - 1)


I don't know exactly why, but after changes made to the YAML file, roles started to be created under the bot role.
Here are the changes I made:
roles:
  #Server Roles
  cat-server_roles:
    name: "┉┉➤ sᴇʀᴠᴇʀ ʀᴏʟᴇs ⋮"
    color: "6c6e7e"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: false
  owner:
    name: "⋞ᴏᴡɴᴇʀ⋡"
    color: "e5e357"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: false
  administrator:
    name: "⋞ᴀᴅᴍɪɴ⋡"
    color: "ed0041"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  moderator:
    name: "⋞ᴍᴏᴅ⋡"
    color: "73c65a"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  booster:
    name: "⋞ʙᴏᴏsᴛᴇʀ⋡"
    color: "fb0399"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  member:
    name: "⋞ᴍᴇᴍʙᴇʀ⋡"
    color: "03d998"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  newbie:
    name: "⋞ɴᴇᴡʙɪᴇ⋡"
    color: "ccc7a"
    hoist: true
    mentionable: true
  #Gender
  cat-gender:
    name: "┉┉┉┉➤ ɢᴇɴᴅᴇʀ ⋮"
    color: "6c6e7e"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: false
  male:
    name: "ᴍᴀʟᴇ"
    color: "007fff"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  female:
    name: "ғᴇᴍ"
    color: "c601e2"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  other:
    name: "ᴏᴛʜᴇʀ〳ɴᴏɴ ʙɪ〳ᴘʀᴇғᴇʀ ɴᴏᴛ ᴛᴏ sᴀʏ"
    color: "03d998"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  #Pronouns
  cat-pronouns:
    name: "┉┉┉➤ ᴘʀᴏɴᴏᴜɴs ⋮"
    color: "6c6e7e"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: false
  he:
    name: "ʜᴇ〳ʜɪᴍ"
    color: "007fff"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  she:
    name: "sʜᴇ〳ʜᴇʀ"
    color: "c601e2"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  they:
    name: "ᴛʜᴇʏ〳ᴛʜᴇᴍ﹝+ᴏᴛʜᴇʀs﹞"
    color: "03d998"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  #Age
  cat-age:
    name: "┉┉┉┉┉┉➤ ᴀɢᴇ ⋮"
    color: "6c6e7e"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: false
  18:
    name: "⊰ᴀɢᴇ⊱﹝+﹞"
    color: "9659b6"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  15:
    name: "⊰ᴀɢᴇ⊱﹝+﹞"
    color: "a060d0"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  13:
    name: "⊰ᴀɢᴇ⊱﹝+﹞"
    color: "a77dc2"
    hoist: false
    mentionable: true
  #default role
  everyone:

Maybe something with alphabetical display or something, I don't know.
